# How can I save a file from JS app to iCloud?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, icloud, icloud-drive, icloud-api

Does iCloud provide anything like the google drive's "[save to drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/savetodrive#add_the_save_to_drive_button_to_a_page)" button or dropbox's "[saver](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/saver)"?

Or what is the easiest way to save a file (e.g. .pdf) from my app (JS/React) to iCloud?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use https://github.com/npomfret/react-native-cloud-fs to copy files to the iCloud

Comment: ..and any luck with my example?

Comment: Ouch, I forgot to specify that it is a web application...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment you could use [RNCloudFs.copyToCloud](https://github.com/npomfret/react-native-cloud-fs) to copy files to the iCloud

Example:

```
const source = {uri: 'https://example.com/foobar.pdf'};
const destination = "/dox/foobar.pdf";
const mimeType = null;
const scope = 'visible';

RNCloudFs.copyToCloud({
  sourcePath: source, 
  targetPath: destination, 
  mimeType: mimeType, 
  scope: scope
})
.then((path) => {
  console.log("File transfer to: ", path, " was successful");
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.warn("File transfer failed with error: ", err);
})
```